# To find the intervals where $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is increasing or decreasing,given $f$ is a real valued function defined on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

If $f$ is a real valued function defined on $[0,\infty)$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f''(x)\gt0 $  $ \forall x $,then Find the intervals in which the function $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is increasing or decreasing

My attempt:
$$h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$$
$$h'(x)=\frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{x^2}$$
So,
$$h'(x)=0$$ when $xf'(x)=f(x)$ or does not exist when $x=0$
and let
$$g(x)=xf'(x)-f(x)$$
$$h''(x)=\frac{(xf''(x))x^2-2xg(x)}{x^4}$$
$$=\frac{x^2f''(x)-2g(x)}{x^3}$$
I don't know how to proceed further

Comment: $h'(0)\neq 0 $ when $x=0$

Comment: I would think that the question is too general to have any definite answer. The intervals of monotonicity can be determined only in specific cases.